# Manipular valores de Drag and Drop sortable com Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-n-drop

### Esquema em imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Problemas:

- **A ordem e quantidade** das caixas da **primeira coluna** não devem ser alteradas. Não consegui deixa-las somente para fim de `DRAG`, ou seja, eu não posso retirar uma caixa da segunda e passar de volta para a `coluna 1`, mas sim entre as colunas do dia da semana e sem gerar cópias.
- Preciso que cada dia, `SEGUNDA, TERÇA, QUARTA...` sejam limitados de acordo com a regra apresentada na imagem **(verificar anexo)**. A ordem não das caixas não importa para cada dia. O que importa é o limite. `Exemplo:` **Nunca em um dia deve-se ter duas caixa que valem um expediente**.
- Quando houver dois cliques nas caixas que estão no dia da semana, a caixa deve sumir e isso acontece, mas com um erro. Não consigo deletar mais de uma caixa com a mesma ***class***.
- O grande desafio é a `QUARTA CAIXA`. Ela pode ser colocada ilimitadamente sobre qualquer limite de caixas dentro dos dias, ou seja: **Na segunda eu posso acrescentar `SOMENTE CAIXAS DO TIPO 4*`*.
- **EXTRA:** como poderia, via `AJAX`, salvar esses valores em uma tabela de banco de dados? Devo colocar `inputs` ao invés de `divs`? Criar um `form`? Ou exista uma forma de detectar o click de um botão e capturar a informação de cada `id="seg"`, `id="ter"`, etc..?

> **O QUE JÁ TENHO**

```js
        var sum = 0;

  $('.nip').sortable({
      revert: 'invalid',
      connectWith: '.nip',
      forcePlaceholderSize: false,
      helper: function(e,li) {
          copyHelper= li.clone().insertAfter(li);
          return li.clone();
      },  
      stop: function(){
          // habilitando todos os sortables
          $('.nip').each(function(){           
              var $this = $(this);
              sum = parseFloat($(this).text());  //ou this.innerHTML, this.innerText
            console.log('SUM: '+ sum);
              $this.css('borderColor','gray');
              $this.sortable('enable');
          });
      }
  });

    /* AQUI ELE REMOVE, MAS REMOVE SOMENTE UM */
  $('ul.ui-sortable li').dblclick(function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });


  $('.nip li').mousedown(function(){
      // Verifique o número de elementos no sortable
      $('.nip').not($(this).parent()).each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    
          if($this.find('.drag').length >= 4){
              $this.css('borderColor','red');
              $this.sortable('disable');
          } else {
              $this.css('borderColor','gray');
              $this.sortable('enable');
          }
      });
  })
```

```css
  
 .nip { display:inline-block; margin:5px; border:1px solid grey; vertical-align:top; }
 .nips { display:inline-block; margin:5px; border:1px solid grey; vertical-align:top; }
 ul { min-width:100px; min-height:60px; }

 li.um { color: #fff; background-color: red; text-align: center; padding: 60px 20px 20px 20px; width:50px; height:60px; margin:5px; border:1px solid silver; }

 li.dois { color: #fff; background-color: blue; text-align: center; padding: 30px 20px 20px 20px; width:50px; height:30px; margin:5px; border:1px solid silver; }

 li.tres { color: #fff; background-color: green; text-align: center; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; width:50px; height:15px; margin:5px; border:1px solid silver; }

 li.quatro { color: #fff; background-color: black; text-align: center; padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px; width:50px; height:7px; margin:5px; border:1px solid silver; }

 .semana{
     width: 960px;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .caixa{
     float: left;
 }

 .caixa p{
  font-family: arial;
     padding: 10px;
     text-align: center;
 }

 #drags{float: left;}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <ul class='nip' id="drags">
     <li class="um">1</li>
     <li class="dois">2</li>
     <li class="tres">3</li>
     <li class="quatro">4</li>
 </ul>

<div class="semana">
 <div class="caixa">
  <p>SEGUNDA</p>
  <ul class='nip' id="seg"></ul>
 </div>
 
 <div class="caixa">
  <p>TERÇA</p>
  <ul class='nip' id="ter"></ul>
 </div>
 
 <div class="caixa"> 
  <p>QUARTA</p>
  <ul class='nip' id="quar"></ul>
 </div>

 <div class="caixa">
  <p>QUINTA</p>
  <ul class='nip' id="quin"></ul>
 </div>
 <div class="caixa">
  <p>SEXTA</p>
  <ul class='nip' id="sext"></ul>
 </div>

 <div class="caixa">
  <p>SÁBADO</p>
  <ul class='nip' id="sab"></ul>
 </div>

 <div class="caixa">
  <p>DOMINGO</p>
  <ul class='nip' id="dom"></ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alguém para ajudar?

Comment: Alguma alma pode ajudar?

Comment: Oi @Lollipop. Sei que já faz mais de um ano que vc postou essa pergunta, mas conseguiu resolver? Imagino que sim, mas caso ainda tenha dúvida, talvez o artigo abaixo possa te ajudar. https://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/